# Online account does not show all Google calendars

Tags: 11.10, gnome, calendar, google-calendar, online-accounts

I added a Google account to the "online accounts" manager of Ubuntu. My Google account has 3 calendars. One private, school and work. Currently only the items from my private calendar are shown in the GNOME 3.2 calendar. I would however very much like to display my school calendar as well in the GNOME 3.2 calendar. Is this possible? If the answer is yes, how can I do this?

PS. When this is not possible where can I comment to request this as a new feature of the upcoming GNOME version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the gnome3 default for Calendars: Evolution.

Click on "open calendars" in the bottom right corner.
Now Evolution should start.
If your calendar is listed on the left, just check the box in front of it.
If not, click the small arrow next to "new" in the upper left corner and choose "calendar".
Select "Google" as type, enter you email address and click "retrieve list".
Now you should be able to select your calendars from the drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you! That is extremely peculiar behaviour - I mean online accounts bring you only 1 calendar. And then once again you must authenticate in Evolution to add more. Ah...

Comment: No longer works - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps